# Keep all rows whose 1st cell matches other rows' 1st cell

Tags: excel, sorting, text, excel-formula, duplicates

In a excel table (500K+ lines), I would like to **keep only those rows**, *all of them*, whose **column A is 100% identical to other rows' column A**. This is irrespective what's in columns B, C, etc., but the rows must be sorted in their entirety (i.e., rows not to be broken up). Rows whose column A is not 100% identical to at least one other row's column A are to be deleted.

I am looking for possible solutions other than using `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=1`.

For example, the original table:

```
coumnA     columnB
abc        123
0xyz       xxx
aaa-123    123
aaa-12     0xyz
0xyz       098
00xyz      098
0xyz       x111xx
```

Keep all occurrences of rows with 100% identical column A:

```
0xyz       xxx
0xyz       098
0xyz       x111xx
```

This formula `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=1`,  identifies multiples of column A and works in small sets of rows. Is there a better, more efficient way to accomplish this **with row numbers that approach the excel sheet's limit** (1,048,576 rows)?

Comment: When you say that `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=1` misses some legitimate duplicate rows, are you sure that the "duplicates" are actually identical - e.g. does one have more trailing spaces than the other?

Comment: Why is `0xyz` the only value from column `A` which appears in your expected output?

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=1` seems to "work" on small samples, but not in 500K lines.

Comment: `0xyz` is the **only** value that occurs **exactly** in more than one row in column A.

Comment: May I suggest that you consider moving your data into a database table if you really have 500K rows?

Comment: i agree with you 100% re database table. i was just trying to see if excel (or notepad++) able to handle a quick sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=1` is to create a PivotTable with ColumnA for ROWS and Count of ColumnA for VALUES. Then lookup the `A` values in the PT and if their count is `1` flag them so with filtering on the flag the rows may be deleted.